# Multiclass tidymodel - class of outcome variable?

Tags: tidyverse, xgboost, multiclass-classification, tidymodels

I want to do multiclass classification, and my y-variable is "character", three levels ("CD", "UC", "IBS")

How can I transform my y-variable into a factor/something the model will accept?

My model code:

```
  boost_tree(trees=50) %>%
  set_engine("xgboost") %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  fit(diagnosis ~ ., data=train)
```

Error in `check_outcome()`:
! For a classification model, the outcome should be a factor.
Backtrace:

1. ... %>% fit(diagnosis ~ ., data = train)
2. parsnip::fit.model_spec(., diagnosis ~ ., data = train)
3. parsnip:::form_xy(...)
4. parsnip:::check_outcome(env$y, object)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before you do anything else (like data splitting or resampling), you can make it a factor via

```
train$diagnosis <- factor(train$diagnosis)
```

See the help files; there are other options that you can set such as the order of the factor levels and so on.